# htaccess rewrite url from different pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

i make this in htaccess file .. for rewrite url from different page

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

and it's works fine ..

now i need to add more as facebook

you can put facebook.com/username

which is : facebook.com/profile.php?username=

& you can put facebook.com/pagename
which is : facebook.com/pages.php?username=

and works fine

from different pages ..

I need to make like this ..

any help ?!

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]   

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: add the wanted page as parameter in url and the rule will know how to read it

Comment: I dont understand more about htaccess .. can you tell me how ?!

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-profile$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-index$ index.php?username=$1 [QSA]

Comment: the url will be like 
http://site.com/username-profile  == For profile

I need result to be like this 
http://site.com/user.Name  == Form profile.php

& 

http://site.com/company.Name == Form company.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex patterns match identically, so you're going to need something to differentiate between pages and people (or redirection to profile.php vs. index.php).

You can accomplish this one of two ways. First, you can go all to one page, let's call it redirect.php. On this page, you could check the id value and then redirect. So like:

```
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ redirect.php?id=$1
```

In redirect.php, you grab `$_GET['id']` and run some query against it to determine if it's a page or person, and then redirect using something like:

```
    header("Location: profile.php?username=".$_GET['id']);
```

If you strictly looking for Facebook related stuff, you can hit the graph API up instead of the database to determine if its a page or person ID. (Not sure if it can exist in both - but I think not).

If you don't have a database or data source to determine if its a page or person, then you'll need to add something to your URL strings to determine, like /pages/{pageid}, which you could then rewrite your rules to:

```
    RewriteRule pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1  # for pages
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1  # for people
```

If you can't use something in your URL and don't have a way to access it via database, then you're out of luck, as you're hitting two identical patterns.

Comment: and make sure that if you encounter the right rule, you stop there, you dont go further and try to match with other rule patterns